# Bit banded struct of 16 bits gives size as 3 bytes as well as incorrect assignments

Tags: c, memory, embedded, stm32

I'm currently writing code for an STM32 MCU to work with a peripheral, to make accessing individual bits easier I used a bit banded struct as follows:

```
typedef struct
{
  uint8_t ch3_unreadconv : 1; // 0
  uint8_t ch2_unreadconv : 1; // 1
  uint8_t ch1_unreadconv : 1; // 2
  uint8_t ch0_unreadconv : 1; // 3
  uint8_t not_used_01    : 2; // 4-5
  uint8_t drdy           : 1; // 6
  uint8_t not_used_02    : 2; // 7-8
  uint8_t err_alw        : 1; // 9
  uint8_t err_ahw        : 1; // 10
  uint8_t err_wd         : 1; // 11
  uint8_t not_used_03    : 2; // 12-13
  uint8_t err_chan       : 2; // 14-15
} fdc_status_reg_t;
fdc_status_reg_t statusReg;

// Assign value 13 to the register.
*((uint16_t*) &statusReg) = 0xD;
```

But when I do `sizeof(statusReg);` I get `3`as the answer. When I assign values to the entire register using the code, the bits are set properly except for the last 2 bits i.e., `err_chan`. I've tried the same on GCC and got similar results to test whether it's an STM specific issue.  After further investigation I found that setting the 7th and 8th bits to two seperate bits seems to fix the issue i.e,

```
typedef struct
 {
     uint8_t ch3_unreadconv : 1; // 0
     uint8_t ch2_unreadconv : 1; // 1
     uint8_t ch1_unreadconv : 1; // 2
     uint8_t ch0_unreadconv : 1; // 3
     uint8_t not_used_01    : 2; // 4-5
     uint8_t drdy           : 1; // 6
     uint8_t not_used_02    : 1; // 7
     uint8_t not_used_02_01 : 1; // 8
     uint8_t err_alw        : 1; // 9
     uint8_t err_ahw        : 1; // 10
     uint8_t err_wd         : 1; // 11
     uint8_t not_used_03    : 2; // 12-13
     uint8_t err_chan       : 2; // 14-15
 } fdc_status_reg_t;
```

Gives the correct output for `sizeof` as 2 bytes. And also gives predicted behaviour for assignment. This (to me) looks like a padding/memory alignment issue, but I do not understand how, I was able recreate this whenever a `uint8_t` was used accross the 7th and 8th bit, but works fine when a `uint16_t` is used across 7-8. Kindly advise on what the issue maybe and possibly a better work around than splitting the bits at 7th bit. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Typo? `} fdc_status_reg_t;
fdc_status_reg statusReg;` (`fdc_status_reg` should be `fdc_status_reg_t`)
`

Comment: @ryyker Ah, my bad, it was a typo. Corrected it now. Thanks.

Comment: 3 is a correct size.  2 is a correct size. You expectation that the size must be 2 is incorrect.  You have the correct understanding though that is it due to padding.

Comment: I think `uint16_t` could tell gcc not to break `7-8` byte.

Comment: [You can not expect any specific result when using bit-fields](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p11): "An implementation may allocate **any addressable storage unit large enough to hold a bit- field**. If enough space remains, a bit-field that immediately follows another bit-field in a structure shall be packed into adjacent bits of the same unit. If insufficient space remains, whether a bit-field that does not fit is put into the next unit or overlaps adjacent units is **implementation-defined**.

Comment: (cont) The order of allocation of bit-fields within a unit (high-order to low-order or low-order to high-order) is **implementation-defined**. The alignment of the addressable storage unit is **unspecified**."  In other words, if you want specific results, or need portability, you simply can't rely on bit-fields.

Comment: You should mention in which way the bits are not set correctly. What do you expect and what do you get?

Comment: @AndrewHenle it is stm32 specific question. uC compilers developers make sure that it is very well defined and documented. All usable compilers: gcc, iar, keil, GH have it very well defined. The uC code will never ported to the UNISYS mainframes so OP do not have to worry too much about the Standard in this case

Comment: @P__J__  And when the code gets ported to another uC that uses another compiler in four years, the bit fields will be entirely different.  I like for my code to act predictably in such circumstances, so I do it right the first time.

Answer (score 5):

The byte count in the first struct is bumping up against a [byte alignment boundary](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGH2K_13.1.0/com.ibm.xlc131.aix.doc/proguide/calgnbit.html) at this field member:

```
uint8_t not_used_02    : 2; // 7-8
```

This results in the bit count being 9 at that point, not 8, thus invoking [bit field padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16692699/bit-field-padding-in-c), accommodating the additional bit by adding one more byte, bringing the byte count to 3.

If you could adjust order of fields within the bit field structs, you can get the byte count down to 2.  Or...

With bit fields, system implementation is not guaranteed to be consistent from system to system, but you can experiment with *your implementation* to obtain the desired outcome.  For example try using a `type` large enough to accommodate all the bits, eg `uint16_t`.  On my system using `uint16_t` resulted in a `sizeof` 2 for the same fields with identical field order:

```
typedef struct
{
  uint16_t ch3_unreadconv : 1; // 0
  uint16_t ch2_unreadconv : 1; // 1
  uint16_t ch1_unreadconv : 1; // 2
  uint16_t ch0_unreadconv : 1; // 3
  uint16_t not_used_01    : 2; // 4-5
  uint16_t drdy           : 1; // 6
  uint16_t not_used_02    : 2; // 7-8
  uint16_t err_alw        : 1; // 9
  uint16_t err_ahw        : 1; // 10
  uint16_t err_wd         : 1; // 11
  uint16_t not_used_03    : 2; // 12-13
  uint16_t err_chan       : 2; // 14-15
} fdc_status_reg_t;
fdc_status_reg_t statusReg;
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use the correct integer size for the struct:

```
typedef struct
 {
     uint16_t ch3_unreadconv : 1; // 0
     uint16_t ch2_unreadconv : 1; // 1
     uint16_t ch1_unreadconv : 1; // 2
     uint16_t ch0_unreadconv : 1; // 3
     uint16_t                : 2; // 4-5
     uint16_t drdy           : 1; // 6
     uint16_t                : 1; // 7
     uint16_t                : 1; // 8
     uint16_t err_alw        : 1; // 9
     uint16_t err_ahw        : 1; // 10
     uint16_t err_wd         : 1; // 11
     uint16_t                : 2; // 12-13
     uint16_t err_chan       : 2; // 14-15
 } fdc_status_reg_t;
```

You do not need the unused fields names

You can also pack the struct

```
 typedef struct
 {
     uint8_t ch3_unreadconv : 1; // 0
     uint8_t ch2_unreadconv : 1; // 1
     uint8_t ch1_unreadconv : 1; // 2
     uint8_t ch0_unreadconv : 1; // 3
     uint8_t                : 2; // 4-5
     uint8_t drdy           : 1; // 6
     uint8_t                : 1; // 7
     uint8_t                : 1; // 8
     uint8_t err_alw        : 1; // 9
     uint8_t err_ahw        : 1; // 10
     uint8_t err_wd         : 1; // 11
     uint8_t                : 2; // 12-13
     uint8_t err_chan       : 2; // 14-15
 } __attribute__((packed)) fdc_status_reg_t1;
```

Here you ahve an exampple:

https://godbolt.org/z/xUhUT-

Comment: I am curious what you see in your implementation for the packed version of your answer.  On mine I saw it increase to 4 bytes.  Using `uint16_t` it sized at 2 bytes.

Comment: @ryyker What do I see? I see 2 bytes. Click the link. Look at the ARM disassembly tab. See the two `word` values.

Comment: That is interesting.  The implementation specific nature if bit-fields reveals itself in these different results.

Comment: @ryyker I am an uC programmer and I use mainly gcc family compilers. I always have the same results.

Comment: I use GCC, CLANG and NI LabWindows/CVI compilers depending on what I am working on.  Almost no uC projects for a few years, mostly library and application development.

Answer (score 2):

Change type to `uint16_t` to "ignore" the byte boundary at `7-8` byte.

The following `1.c` source file, when compiled with `arm-none-eabi-gdb 9.1` and exeucted under simlator in `arm-none-eabi-gdb`, outputs `2` for the `sizeof`:

```
$ cat 1.c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct
{
  uint16_t ch3_unreadconv : 1; // 0
  uint16_t ch2_unreadconv : 1; // 1
  uint16_t ch1_unreadconv : 1; // 2
  uint16_t ch0_unreadconv : 1; // 3
  uint16_t not_used_01    : 2; // 4-5
  uint16_t drdy           : 1; // 6
  uint16_t not_used_02    : 2; // 7-8
  uint16_t err_alw        : 1; // 9
  uint16_t err_ahw        : 1; // 10
  uint16_t err_wd         : 1; // 11
  uint16_t not_used_03    : 2; // 12-13
  uint16_t err_chan       : 2; // 14-15
} fdc_status_reg_t;
int main() {
    printf("sizeof(fdc_status_reg_t)=%d\n", (int)sizeof(fdc_status_reg_t));
}

$ arm-none-eabi-gcc -specs=rdimon.specs ./1.c && arm-none-eabi-gdb -ex 'target sim' -ex 'load' -ex 'run' -ex quit -quiet ./a.out
Reading symbols from ./a.out...
(No debugging symbols found in ./a.out)
Connected to the simulator.
Loading section .init, size 0x18 lma 0x8000
Loading section .text, size 0xbf8c lma 0x8018
Loading section .fini, size 0x18 lma 0x13fa4
Loading section .rodata, size 0x30c lma 0x13fc0
Loading section .ARM.exidx, size 0x8 lma 0x142cc
Loading section .eh_frame, size 0x4 lma 0x142d4
Loading section .init_array, size 0x8 lma 0x242d8
Loading section .fini_array, size 0x4 lma 0x242e0
Loading section .data, size 0xad4 lma 0x242e8
Start address 0x80e8
Transfer rate: 421280 bits in <1 sec.
Starting program: /tmp/a.out 
sizeof(fdc_status_reg_t)=2
[Inferior 1 (process 42000) exited normally]
```

Additionally you could add `__attribute__((__packet__))` just to be sure.

[Bit-field Packing in GCC and Clang by Josh Kunz](http://jkz.wtf/bit-field-packing-in-gcc-and-clang) I think was the best explanation I found how gcc behaves with bitfields and different types.

Comment: `__attribute__((__packet__))` nothing like this exists. What **packet** ? IP, MODBUS?

Answer (score -1):

You mention bit-banding (in the title), but you need to refer to the compiler documentation (armcc example) to determine whether and how it uses bit-banding to implement bit-fields.

Bit-banding is an efficient way of accessing *single* bits, but members of more than one bit would require more than one read if read from the bit-band region, so the compiler will instead read a *word* from the regular memory region, and for that to be efficient, spanning a word boundary would be avoided, so the 2-bit field in bits 7 and 8 will force a gap.  That is to say bit-banding is not relevant for fields of more than one bit.

It is certainly not an STM32 specific issue, but rather an ARM Cortex-M3/M4 issue.  Bit-banding is not implemented on Cortex-M7 - so also not all STM32.

When bit-banding is not used, no field will span a word boundary in any case.  Using larger unit type such as `uint32_t` will avoid that in this case.

Comment: no he means bitfields and ARM documentation will not help him

Comment: @P__J__  He is targeting an STM32 and mentions bit-banding in the title.  If his assumption is that bit-fields are implemented using bit-banding that that deserves discussion.  The last paragraph covers the situation where bit-banding is not used.  The explanatory link to bit-banding support by armcc was omitted - corrected.  The point is compilers can exploit bit-banding to implement single-bit bit-fields, so it is not unreasonable to assume that that is what he is thinking of.

Comment: he probably even did not heard about it. BTW it was a one of the weirdest ARM ideas, limiting buses and completely ignored by the programmers. It has disappeared in the M7

Comment: @P__J__ Clearly he has heard of it, its right there in the question.  He may of course not understand it, and may be confusing it with bitfields.  Being ignored by programmers is not an issue in this case; it is the compiler that would be exploiting it.  Also not being included in a different ARM processor series is also irrelevant; M7 does not supersede M3 or M4 - they all remain current for different classes of application.  As it happens I have used bit banding (directly) in a number of cases - but the benefits and usage certainly hardly justify the die space it probably takes to implement.

Comment: No he just calls the bitfileld bitband. IMO nothing more, nothing else